# How to display API which is in JSON to a View, using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, json

I have an API created which I call from the URL and upon hitting the API I get a response. Here is my Controller.

```
adminApp.controller('PollController', function($scope,$window,$timeout, $routeParams, $http, $location) {   
         var story_id = 1;  
          $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: ""+story_id,
          }).
          success(function(response) {
            // console.log(response);
            //displayMessage('Sent','200px');
            $scope.poll = response.polls;
            console.log("======================");
            console.log(response.polls);
            console.log("======================");
            console.log(response.polls[0].options[0].votes);
          }).
          error(function(response) {
              console.log(response || "Request failed");
          });



});
```

And when I hit the API, I get the following.

```
{
  "num_polls": 1,
  "polls": [
    {
      "total_votes": 2,
      "options": [
        {
          "votes": "2",
          "id": "2"
        }
      ],
      "id": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to access the polls[0].options[0].vote using Console log which works fine, but how do I display it in the view using AngularJS?

I tried this but did not work. So how do I access the details from the API?

```
<tr ng-repeat="tableDetail in poll">
<td ng-bind="tableDetail.polls[0].options[0].votes"></td>
<td ng-bind="tableDetail.id "></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the following because with `ng-repeat` you iterate aver the items of the array so you don't have to use the index :

```
<tr ng-repeat="tableDetail in poll">
    <td>{{tableDetail.options[0].votes}}</td>
    <td>{{tableDetail.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This still iterates over the key/value pair in the object, not an array. You would need a different iteration (`(k, v) in poll`) and to access the insides differently

Comment: @casraf it is an array since `$scope.poll = response.polls` so it would be equals to `[{"total_votes": 2,"options": [ {"votes": "2","id": "2"}]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
<tr ng-repeat="tableDetail in poll">
<td>
{{tableDetail.polls.options.votes}}
</td>
<td> {{tableDetail.id}} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I didn't pay attention but what you wrote is not correct: `poll` is in the scope and not the whole object and `options` is an array